# Как на CSS сделать центрирование img внутри div по вертикали и горизонтали?

Tags: css, css3

Есть `div`, внутри него `img` произвольного размера. Надо сделать так чтобы центр `div` и `img` были одинаковыми, нагляднее на картинке:

[image: Центрирование]

Про `margin: 0 auto` выравнивания по горизонтали знаю, но как совместить это с вертикальным выравниванием?

Answer (score 1):

Можешь поизменять размеры фото [здесь](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PRVrZM).

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html,body,.items{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.items{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
img{
  display:block;
  max-width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://get.wallhere.com/photo/women-model-blonde-minidress-red-photography-dress-fashion-hair-clothing-color-girl-beauty-lady-leg-blond-hairstyle-photo-shoot-abdomen-human-body-136579.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## 6 способов центрирования элемента неизвестного размера по вертикали и горизонтали

**Вариант №1: table-cell**

Самый древний вариант, которым пользовались на заре Интернета и во времена рассвета табличной вёрстки. Таблицами уже давно никто не верстает, но можно имитировать их поведение через CSS ради достижения результата:

```css
.block {
   height: 180px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}

.block-cell {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <div class="block-cell">
         <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939634424966270976/G5c285dH_bigger.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант №2: position absolute**

Один из моих любимых вариантов. Идеально подходит для позиционирования попапов – они должны быть поверх остального контента, а их высота никогда неизвестна, как и высота экрана пользователя.

```css
.block {
   height: 180px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   position: relative;
}

.block img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939634424966270976/G5c285dH_bigger.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №3: line-height**

Один из самых глупых вариантов, который хоть и подходит для выравнивание блока неизвестной высоты, но требует фиксированную высоту родителя (в других способах высота родителя указана лишь для примера). Кстати, этот способ также не подойдет для многострочного текста.

```css
.block {
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   line-height: 180px;
   text-align: center;
}

.block img {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939634424966270976/G5c285dH_bigger.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №4: центрирование через псевдоэлемент**

Мой самый любимый способ. Несмотря на то, что в последнее время стал использовать flexbox – выравнивание через псевдоэлемент навсегда останется в моём сердце.

```css
.block {
   height: 180px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   text-align: center;
}

.block:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.block img {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939634424966270976/G5c285dH_bigger.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №5: Flexbox**

Один из современных и самых простых способов центрирования – использование `display: flex`.

```css
.block {
   height: 180px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939634424966270976/G5c285dH_bigger.jpg">
</div>
```

**Вариант №6: CSS Grid**

Grid – наше ближайшее и светлое будущее! Никогда прежде выравнивание блоков не была такой простой и вряд ли в скором времени что-то превзойдет CSS Grid. Хотя этот пример и похож очень на предыдущий, возможности Grid гораздо шире. В общем, если не научились работать с flexbox – можете смело его пропускать и разбираться с CSS Grid.

```css
.block {
   height: 180px; /* for Demo only */
   background: black; /* for Demo only */
   display: grid;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939634424966270976/G5c285dH_bigger.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/bv3csdkg/6/

```css
#out{
  position: relative;
}

#cent{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="out" style="width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: red">
  <div id="cent" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы же передвигаете на 50 процентов относительно размера картинки, а не родителя https://jsfiddle.net/bv3csdkg/4/

Answer (score 0):

Выравнивать элементы по вертикали стало проще с появлением flexbox

```css
.container {
width:300px;
height: 200px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container img {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://htmlbook.ru/themes/hb/img/logo.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы `margin: auto;` работал и по вертикали, нужно чтобы блок (в нашем случае имг), был с `position: absolute;` на все стороны (`left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;`).

```css
.img-block {display: block; width: 300px; height: 250px; background: red; position: relative;}
.img-block img {display: block; width: 200px; height: 100px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
</div>
```

Comment: Ещё, чтобы блок с `position: absolute` не вылезал за края родителя, нужно чтобы родитель имел `position: relative;`

Answer (score -1):

```css
.image {
width: 300px;
}
.image-box {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 0;
padding-top: 70%;
}
.image-content {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.image-content img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
max-width: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(0,-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
-o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

```html
    <div class="image">
      <div class="image-box">
        <div class="image-content"><img src="http://i.ucrazy.ru/files/i/2012.10.16/1350382464_1325775613_4.jpg" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```